# How can Remove other work-spaces from Visual studio TFS 2019?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, workspace

However VS 2019 is the best IDE, sometimes we want to do somethings and we can not do it. for example, you work on a project and suddenly your PC is crashed and you have some class check out on TFS.

In new PC when you get source you see some sources check out with your user in another pc and you can not check-in or undo them in VS 2019. What can you do?

Answer (score 0):

**A tip for solving the problem with another work-space in TFS**

*Solution*

**The best way that I find without any writing commands is:**

Install VS 2013 and after that get Power Tools for TFS vs 2013

After install power tools, when you get the source with vs 2013 and go to source control explorer, you can right-click on your project and go to **find--->findByStatus**

and click on find.

you see all files which are checked out by other workspaces and you can undo them

*that's easy*

Next step. close vs 2013 and open VS 2019 and get your sources and start again write code. (please write clean code :))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Attrice TFS Sidekicks available [here](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm#tfssidekicks2015) there are multiple versions for different Visual Studio but they all work against 2019.  From the workspace sidekick you can list and remove old workspaces.

Also you can run from the TF.exe command line do remove old workspaces Microsoft doc available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workspace-command?view=azure-devops)